# jQuery Validate for multiple forms on a page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery Validation plugin on my website. I need to validate two separate forms and use ajax to submit them to two different PHP pages. I am new to JavaScript, but have done a lot of research regarding this, however, I am still stuck.

This is what I have come up with so far... How can I validate and submit one form to `processA.php` and the second form to `processB.php`. Each form has different fields. Is it possible to add a second `submitHandler`?

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : 'processA.php',// write code to send mail in mail.php
                data    : $(form).serialize(),
                cache   : false,
                dataType: 'text',
                success : function (serverResponse) { 
                      alert('mail sent successfully.'); 
                },
                error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert('error sending mail');
                }
            });
            return false; // Temporary
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please only use back-ticks for inline code, not for code blocks.  Use the `{}` button to format a block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have two different `submitHandler` callback functions within one instance of the `.validate()` method.  When you call the `.validate()` method within a jQuery `.each()`... you are intentionally applying the *same options* to every `form` targeted by your `.each()`.

---

Instead, put the corresponding URL within the `action` attribute of each `form` tag...

```
<form action="processA.php" ...

<form action="processB.php" ...
```

The use [jQuery's `.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the correct URL from each `action`...

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                ....
                url: $(form).attr('action'), // <- the correct URL for this form
                ....
            });
            return false; // Temporary
        }
    });
});
```